# Implementing modules loading support using GTK+ 3 libs

Tags: module, gtk3

I'm porting a old app (GTK+ 2) to GTK+ 3, that application uses gmodule to support 'plugins' functionality, it makes use of functions like `g_module_build_path` and etc..

My question is, what's the right way to do this using GTK+ 3 libs, since gmodule is GTK+ 2 only.

A documentation, a example, anything is very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, I've found browsing on gedit's code, that is use `libpeas`, it's the correct way to implement 'plugins' functionality.

A very simple example can be found on libpeas source [code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libpeas/tree/peas-demo)